# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException in SQL database connectivity

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

This is my code. When I run it, I get error:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Can someone please help me?

```
form_()
{
    setSize(265,500);
    setVisible(true);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    add(l1);
    add(t1);
    add(l2);
    add(t2);
    add(l3);
    add(t3);
    add(l4);
    add(t5);
    add(l5);
    add(t4);
    add(b);
    b.addActionListener(this);

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource()==b) {
        int x = 0;
        String s1 = t1.getText();
        String s2 = t2.getText();
        String s3 = t3.getText();
        char[] c = t5.getPassword();
        String s5 = new String(c);
        String s4 = t4.getText();


        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?useSSL=false", "******", "********");

            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO reg1 values(?,?,?,?,?");
            ps.setString(1, s1);
            ps.setString(2, s2);
            ps.setString(3, s3);
            ps.setString(4, s4);
            ps.setString(5, s5);
            int rs = ps.executeUpdate();
            x++;
            if(x>0)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(b,"Data saved Successfully");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO reg1 values(?,?,?,?,?"); this is the mistake in your code. you should try it this way con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO reg1 values(?,?,?,?,?)");

Comment: It should be ("INSERT INTO reg1 values(?,?,?,?,?)"); isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you forget a parenthesis in `"INSERT INTO reg1 values(?,?,?,?,?"` 
it should be like that : `"INSERT INTO reg1 values(?,?,?,?,?)"`

Answer (score 0):

You have messed up with the parathesis(SQL syntax). Add 1 `')'` after 
last `?`. which resulted in [SQLSyntaxErrorException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLSyntaxErrorException.html)

I have updated the snippet:

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO reg1 values(?,?,?,?,?)");
            ps.setString(1, s1);
            ps.setString(2, s2);
            ps.setString(3, s3);
            ps.setString(4, s4);
            ps.setString(5, s5);
```